# From time to time, the Laptop performs memory dump during Blue Screen of death

Tags: windows-7, windows

My laptop from time to time displays the blue screen of death and performs a memory dump. When the laptop is rebooted from the memory dump, I get the follow error. I have since performed a system backup restore but still couldn't make the problem go away. Please help!

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  BlueScreen   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3   Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:   BCCode:   1e
>   BCP1: 0000000000000000   BCP2:    0000000000000000
>   BCP3: 0000000000000000   BCP4:    0000000000000000   OS Version:  6_1_7601
>   Service Pack: 1_0   Product:  768_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\041114-18954-01.dmp
>   C:\Users\Y470\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-73289-0.sysdata.xml
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

from the Event Viewer I found the following errors

Critical: Kernel Power

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This
>   error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or
>   lost power unexpectedly.

1.

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000001e (0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000,
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in:
>   C:\windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 041114-18954-01.

2.

> WLAN Extensibility Module has failed to start.
>
> Module Path: C:\windows\System32\IWMSSvc.dll Error Code: 87

3

> Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the
>   DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0x74E50B01251D.
>   The following error occurred: 0x79. Your computer will continue to try
>   and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP)
>   server.

`Bluescreenviewer` highlighted `ntoskrnl.exe` in red

Comment: Information from `Bluescreenviewer` would be helpful but based on WLAN error it sounds like the problem is the WLAN device driver.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you Ramhound, How can I get the information from the Bluescreenviewer? Every time the blue screen comes on, it automatically goes away after the memory dump, the time was too short to capture what was written on the screen

Comment: You just download it and post what drivers were loaded when the BSOD happen

Comment: @Ramhound the loaded driver ("in red" from Bluescreenviewer) is the ntoskrnl.exe

Comment: There were more drivers loaded.  Update the question itself.

Comment: @user22105 First you can [disable the automatic restart](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/74644/how-to-disable-automatic-restarts-when-windows-crashes/). Then you can copy the whole `C:\Windows\Minidump` folder to the desktop, compress it in a .7z/.zip archive, and upload it somewhere (e.g. http://ge.tt/about). Finally, post the link here for further diagnosis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ran that C:\windows\MEMORY.DMP through a debuger like Windbg? It'll tell you what module is causing the problem, probably from that driver.

If you see it's caused by the WLAN driver then re-install or check for a later version